# C How to properly store sqlite3 rows of data?

Tags: c, sqlite

I've been working in  `C` with `sqlite3` on a program that needs to store more than 1 row of data into a variable for future processing. The program uses a database of products with each product having a name, a price per unit, a category and quantity of said product avalible. Normally for statements like `Select * from Products;` we use the `sqlite3_exec` function and the needed `callback function` like this:

```
#include <sqlite3.h>
#include <stdio.h>



int callback(void *, int, char **, char **);


int main(void) {

sqlite3 *db;
char *err_msg = 0;

int rc = sqlite3_open("test.db", &db);

if (rc != SQLITE_OK) {

    fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open database: %s\n", 
            sqlite3_errmsg(db));
    sqlite3_close(db);

    return 1;
}

char *sql = "SELECT * FROM Cars";

rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sql, callback, 0, &err_msg);

if (rc != SQLITE_OK ) {

    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to select data\n");
    fprintf(stderr, "SQL error: %s\n", err_msg);

    sqlite3_free(err_msg);
    sqlite3_close(db);

    return 1;
} 

sqlite3_close(db);

return 0;
}

int callback(void *NotUsed, int argc, char **argv, 
                char **azColName) {

NotUsed = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++) {

    printf("%s = %s\n", azColName[i], argv[i] ? argv[i] : "NULL");
}

printf("\n");

return 0;
}
```

Now the code above only displays all the rows in the table. I want to store the data to process it further. This is the code I wrote to try that. The problem is it prints duplicate rows as well. Another thing I thought about trying was modifying the callback function to take an extra parameter to store each row but I do not understand how to specify the new parameter.

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<sqlite3.h>

void display_all_products(char *destination)
{
sqlite3 *db;
sqlite3_stmt *stmt;
char *err_msg = 0;
int step;
int rc = sqlite3_open("test.db", &db);
if(rc != SQLITE_OK)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Problem opening Database: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
    sqlite3_free(err_msg);
        sqlite3_close(db);
}
char *sql = "Select * from Products;";
rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sql, -1, &stmt, 0);

    if (rc != SQLITE_OK ) 
{
        fprintf(stderr, "Problem retrieving data: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
        sqlite3_free(err_msg);
        sqlite3_close(db);
    }

while(1)
{
    step = sqlite3_step(stmt);
    if (step == SQLITE_ROW)
    {
        strcat(destination, "Product name : ");
        strcat(destination, sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 1));
        strcat(destination, "\n");
        strcat(destination, "Price per unit : ");
        strcat(destination, sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 2));
        strcat(destination, "\n");
        strcat(destination, "Category of requested article : ");
        strcat(destination, sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 3));
        strcat(destination, "\n");
        strcat(destination, "Quantity avalible on stock : ");
        strcat(destination, sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 4));
        strcat(destination, "\n");
        strcat(destination, "-----------------------------------------------\n");
        printf("%s", destination);
    }
    else
    {
        break;
    }
}
sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
sqlite3_close(db);

}

int main()
{
sqlite3 *db;
sqlite3_stmt *stmt;
char msg[2000] = " ";
display_all_products(msg);
// do something with msg here

return 0;


}
```

Would like to know what else I could do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to make it work. It is all in the documentation after carefully reading it several times.

```
int callback(void *notUsed, int argc, char **argv, 
            char **azColName) {

NotUsed = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++) {

//printf("%s = %s\n", azColName[i], argv[i] ? argv[i] : "NULL");
strcat(notUsed, azColName[i]);
strcat(notUsed, " = ");
strcat(notUsed, argv[i] ? argv[i] : "NULL");
}

printf("\n");

return 0;
} 

void display_all_products(char *test)
{
sqlite3 *db;
sqlite3_stmt *stmt;
char *err_msg = 0;
int rc = sqlite3_open("test.db", &db);
if(rc != SQLITE_OK)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Problem opening Database: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
    sqlite3_free(err_msg);
        sqlite3_close(db);
}
char *sql = "Select * from Products;";
rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sql, callback, test, &err_msg);

    if (rc != SQLITE_OK ) 
{
        fprintf(stderr, "Problem retrieving data: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
        sqlite3_free(err_msg);
        sqlite3_close(db);
    }
sqlite3_close(db);

}
int main()
{
sqlite3 *db;
sqlite3_stmt *stmt;
char msg[4000] = " ";
display_all_products(msg);
// do something with msg here

return 0;


}
```

The difference is in the `callback` function body.
Also when we call the `sqlite3_exec()` function we pass the `test` pointer instead of 0 as I did previously.

```
 rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sql, callback, test, &err_msg);
```

> The 4th argument to sqlite3_exec() is relayed through to the 1st argument of each callback invocation.

This means that the 4th argument to `sqlite3_exec()` can be made to hold the value of the first argument to the `callback` function which I was confused about after reading documentation the first time.